# AJAX PHP Upload file to database

Tags: php, sybase

I am working on a script that uploads a file, calls a php script via ajax that uploads it to a folder on the server. This part is working correctly. The next step is to then take this file and insert it into a database (I know its not best practise but I have to due to exising db/software constraints) but I cant seem to get this to work at all.

I'll leave out the ajax as that is working correctly, here's the PHP:

```
$upload_dir = "./uploads";

$result["status"]  = "200";
$result["message"] = "ERROR!";

if (isset($_FILES['file']))
{
    echo "Uploading File...<br />";
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
    {
        $filename    = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $destination = 'uploads/' . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destination);

        //THIS IS THE SECTION THAT DOESN'T WORK CORRECTLY. IT JUST DOES NOTHING AT ALL
        //upload the image as a blob
        $image = file_get_contents ($destination);

        //see if there is anything already stored in blob
        $sqlcheck = "select id from blobstore where id='$custid'";
        $result   = sasql_query($connect, "$sqlcheck");

        if (!isset($row['id']))
        {
            $sql = "update blobstore set class='j', id='$custid', blob='".sasql_real_escape_string($connect,$image)."', createdby='$userid', createdat='". date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i')."' where id='$custid' ";
            $insert = sasql_query($connect, "$sql");
        }
        else if (isset($row['id']))
        {
            $sql = "insert into blobstore (class, id, blob, createdby, createdat) VALUES ('j','$custid', '".sasql_real_escape_string($connect,$image)."','$userid', '". date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i')."') ";
            $insert = sasql_query($connect, "$sql");
        }

        //WHEN I INCLUDE THE ABOVE SECTION TO UPLOAD THE IMAGE TO THE DB THIS ALSO RETURNS NOTHING, WHEREAS IF I TAKE OUT THAT SECTION IT RETURNS AS EXPECTED
        $result["status"]  = "100";
        $result["message"] = "File was uploaded successfully!";
    }
} 
elseif ($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE) 
{
    $result["status"]  = "200";
    $result["message"] = "The file is too big.";    
} 
else 
{
    $result["status"]  = "500";
    $result["message"] = "Unknown error.";
}
```

When I run this I am getting the error

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value

This error goes when I remove the following code

> $result["status"]  = "100";
>               $result["message"] = "File was uploaded successfully!";

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `blob` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html either use another name for it or wrap it using backticks.

Comment: Where is that error? I'n the SQL? I have tested the SQL and this is working correctly...

Comment: Are you checking for errors? Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: this is what I'm asking you, the only place that I can see I've used the word blob is within the sql query, which I have tested? Thanks

Comment: `blob` is appearing more than once. `blob='".sasql_real_escape_string` and `(class, id, blob, createdby, createdat)` unless there's something I'm not quite grasping.

Comment: making that change just returns a syntax error.

Comment: Plus, you're using `sybase` so TBH, I don't know if reserved words need to be backticked using that. I've added the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: Wait, I found something http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Alhakeywords.htm which states *"Some keywords in SQL are also reserved words. To use a reserved word in a SQL statement as an identifier, you must enclose the word in double quotes. Many, but not all, of the keywords that appear in SQL statements are reserved words. For example, you must use the following syntax to retrieve the contents of a table named SELECT."* - So try using double quotes instead of backticks as I originally suggested.

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't think that the issue is the SQL statement though as I have tested this and I had this working in another script

Comment: You're welcome, wish I could help you out more. However, try using `var_dump($insert);` and/or `var_dump($sql);` to see what's being passed through, as well as adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything more.